# Pull down AWS S3 bucket locally in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have a task of pulling down assets which are stored on an AWS S3 bucket and storing those in a local project using Laravel. Also, the files are encrypted.

I need to write a script to do this.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is the s3 bucket added as a storage driver? Do you mean you need to pull(move/copy) the files from s3 storage of laravel to local server where laravel is running?

Comment: When you ask if I have the s3 bucket added as a storage driver, I assume you mean do I have it as a filesystem disk in filesystems.php within the disks array. Within the project code is the ability to upload files and have them be saved to the AWS s3 bucket so to answer your question, I think it is added as a storage driver. And I do need to move/copy the files from the s3 bucket on AWS to my local Laravel project.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have following disks :

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('S3_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('S3_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('S3_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
        'http'    => [
            'connect_timeout' => 30,
        ],
    ],

],
```

Then you can copy file using :

```
if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists('path/yourfile.txt')){

    Storage::disk('local')->writeStream('path/yourfile.txt', Storage::disk('s3')->readStream('path/yourfile.txt'));
}
```

To move the file :

```
if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists('path/yourfile.txt')){

    Storage::disk('local')->writeStream('path/yourfile.txt', Storage::disk('s3')->readStream('path/yourfile.txt'));

    Storage::disk('s3')->delete('path/yourfile.txt');
}
```

If you have set default disk then you can skip mentioning it spefically and directly do `Storage::something()`

**Moving all files from s3 to local disk :**

Considering you have different disks which are not on the same server, you need to do little bit extra as compared to both disks on the same server :

```
$s3Files = Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles();
foreach ($s3Files as $file) {

    // copy
    Storage::disk('local')->writeStream($file, Storage::disk('s3')->readStream($file));

    // move
    Storage::disk('local')->writeStream($file, Storage::disk('s3')->readStream($file));
    Storage::disk('s3')->delete($file);
}
```

Or You can move the delete() after the entire moving and delete all files together like :

`Storage::disk('s3')->delete(Storage::disk('s3')->allFiles());`

which is essentially similar but just one function call.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response Mihir. Instead of manually entering the filename in the exists function, is there a way just to pull down all files (without checking if it exists) as I may not necessarily know the filenames?

Comment: That's awesome Mihir. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Thats great. You can accept the answer if you find it useful to close the thread :)